# Log all mysql queries

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, relational-database, mysql-workbench

We have our release cycle such that every Thursday we upload chunks on the staging server. We use git to manage our code versioning. We have a mysql db which is as big as 3gb. As we tend to make changes to our mysql db we end up uploading the latest db again on staging server every week. This is time consuming as we have to upload the sql files to our staging server which is hosted at at remote location.

What I am looking for is if we can get our local db to log all queries that update db either the structure or records and then use all these queries to update the db on staging server incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

the thing you are asking is exactly what a master/slave or replication does. if you setup such topologies for your mysql instances it does same thing you want, but i have to add it has its own difficulties too.